# How to include js parts of code inside another js file with code. [Prepros]

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, concatenation, prepros

Prepros has useful feature:

```
//@prepros-prepend filename.js
```

which includes js file at the **beginning** of current one, but I need to include files **inside** jquery document.ready statement, which would look like so:

```
$(function(){
  //@prepros-include code1.js
  //@prepros-include code2.js
  //@prepros-include code3.js
  //@prepros-include code3.js
  ...
});
```

Is that somehow possible, or have you any other solution how to concatenate a lot of js-fragments which would be bound inside jquery `$(function(){...});` wrapper?

[edit] Ps. I don't want to write `$(function(){...});` inside of each partial-file.

Comment: Your best solution is probably something like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/). These allow you to build modular JavaScript for use on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you use google the first link wil be this one of [jquery home page](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)
But if you want to include in your js file other js files use this.

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    alert("No file found");
});
```

ofcourse you can easily easy a line like this.

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js" );
```

Comment: I'm interested in concatenation files into one output code, in this case Ajax requests would affect page loading time, and won't work on file:/// protocol, which in very few cases is a useful thing as it doesn't require setting up a webserver. Ps. if I would decide for ajax solution I'd use Require.js instead of jquery http://requirejs.org/